# how to add these files(*.jar) in classpath ? Without any IDE

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I'm a newbie with java. I currently work on JDBC and face many problems but many are solved.

For this problem I add *.jar(ucanacces version 5.0.0) files in my folder where my JdbcEx.java file  and (*.accdb) placed. 
When I compile my .java file, I encounter error

> java.land.ClassNotFoundException : net.ucanacces.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver

When I compile .java file with
`D:\java coding\Lecture 14>java -cp D:\java coding\Lecture 14;D:\java coding\Lecture 14\libucanaccess-5.0.0.jar;D:\java coding\Lecture 14\lib\commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar;D:\java coding\Lecture 14\lib\hsqldb-2.5.0.jar;D:\java coding\Lecture 14\lib\jackcess-3.0.1.jar Lecture 14`

I get error

> Error: Could not find or load main class coding\Lecture
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: coding\Lecture

How can I fix this?

```
import java.sql.*;
public class JdbcEx{
   public static void main( String args[ ] ){
  try{

      Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
      String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/java coding/Lecture 14/lib/PersonInfo.accdb";
      Connection con = null;
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
      Statement st = con.createStatement();
      String sql = "SELECT * FROM person";
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
      while(rs.next()){
          String name = rs.getString("pName");
          String add = rs.getString("address");
          String ph = rs.getString("phoneNum");
          System.out.println(name + "  " + add + "  " + ph);
     }
     con.close();
   }catch(Exception sqlExp){
          System.out.println(sqlExp);
          sqlExp.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
}
```

Comment: Paths on the command line with spaces in them, like this `D:\java coding\Lecture 14`, need to be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Note that `java` doesn't compile, it executes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the path of your jars. The way command prompts/shells process commands means that normally a space indicates the next command line option. To avoid this, you need to enclose the entire class path list after `-cp` in double quotes, ie:

`java -cp "D:\java coding\Lecture 14;D:\java coding\Lecture 14\lib\ucanaccess-5.0.0.jar;D:\java coding\Lecture 14\lib\commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar;D:\java coding\Lecture 14\lib\hsqldb-2.5.0.jar;D:\java coding\Lecture 14\lib\jackcess-3.0.1.jar" Lecture 14`

However, it would be easier to avoid spaces in paths altogether, and for example use directory `JavaCoding` and `Lecture14`.

Given you're executing from the directory `D:\java coding\Lecture 14`, you could also use relative paths:

`java -cp .;lib\ucanaccess-5.0.0.jar;lib\commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar;lib\hsqldb-2.5.0.jar;lib\jackcess-3.0.1.jar Lecture 14`

As there are no spaces in the path, the double quotes aren't necessary

BTW: you can further simplify your class path by using a wildcard:

`java -cp ".;lib\*" Lecture 14`